# Android-webrtc Stream data from other than camera source directly to webbrowser

Tags: webrtc, apprtcdemo

UseCase - I am using android projection API to capture my android device screen. The output is displayed in a SurfaceView. Next i want to project surfaceview data to a web browser using Webrtc.

I have seen lots of example which uses device camera and stream it output to web browser. how can i stream a video being played on surfaceView/TextureView to web browser.

Comment: Hey @shubendrak, do you have any updates?